# Can i write redirect rules in Amazon cloudfront?

Tags: url-rewriting, amazon-cloudfront

I am using Apache webserver's mod_rewrite module to redirect from the old domain to new domain. Example

RewriteRule /page1.html /page2.html [L]

I am using Amazon cloudfront to cache these files. Please let me know can i write similar rules in Amazon cloudfront so that i can avoid these traffic to webserver.

Thanks
Siva.

Comment: Your question says you are redirecting from one domain to another, but the example rewrite rule appears to be rewriting internally from one page to another, without a redirect.  Please clarify.

Comment: In the webserver i am handling the domain1 to domain2 redirects by having multiple virtulhosts.  i would like to know whether i can enable these rules like  1) domain1 to domain2 2) page1 to page 2  on the CDN level .

Answer (score 0):

No you can't - but there's no need to configure the re-directs in CloudFront.

Get your origin webserver to issue the redirects you need, and CloudFront will cache them for you (after all it is just another HTTP response), Once the redirect has been served and is cached, subsequent requests for a resource are served the redirect from CloudFront's cache - rather than your webserver.